# Using seperate in tidyr r based conditionally using ifelse

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to seperate a column into multiple columns using tidyr. I tried initially using if..else and it wouldnt work and when I looked at stackoverflow the suggestion was to use ifelse. So I tried using ifelse and it still doessnt work. Below is what I am trying to do when I am getting the error :

```
testdata <- tibble::tribble(
  ~config,       ~construct, ~var,
  1, "This_is_line_1",   12,
  2, "This_is_dot_2",   15,
  3, "This_is_dot_1 ",   15,
  4, "This_is_line_2",   12,
  5, "This_is_line_3",   12,
  6, "This_is_dot_4",   15,
  7, "This_is_dot_3 ",   15,
  8, "This_is_line_4",   12
)


  ifelse(testdata$var == 12,
         tidyr::separate(testdata$construct, into = c("etc1","etc2", "etc3","etc4"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE),
         tidyr::separate(testdata$construct, into = c("etc1","etc2", "etc5","etc4"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE)
         )
```

Error message : `Error in UseMethod("separate_") :  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"`

Thank you.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired result here?

Comment: based on the condition it should separate into different columns. If var =12 column 3 is `etc3` else its `etc5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple `ifelse` operator doesn't do well with return different shaped data. Here's a different strategy that partitions the data, then does the conditional transformation, then merges everything back together

```
testdata %>% 
  group_split(is12 = var==12) %>% 
  map(function(d) {
    into = if (d$is12[1]) {
      c("etc1","etc2", "etc3","etc4")
    } else {
      c("etc1","etc2", "etc5","etc4")
    }
    tidyr::separate(d, construct, into = into, sep = "_", remove = FALSE)
  }) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% select(-is12)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do a `separate` first and then change the column names with `rename`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
testdata %>%
   separate(construct, into = str_c("etc", 1:4), sep="_", remove = FALSE) %>% 
   group_split(grp = var == 12) %>%
   map_dfr(~  if(!first(.x$grp)) .x %>% 
         rename(etc5 = etc3) else .x) %>% 
   select(-grp)
```